# How to encode $|i \rightarrow j \rangle$ using binary string?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-walks

We define the quantum state on a complex network in the form,

$$\mid\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}\psi_{i,j}(t)\lvert
 i\to j\rangle, $$

where $N$ is the total number of nodes, the state $|i \to j⟩$ resides on the node $i$ and is to hop to the adjacent site $j$, while $k_i$ is the number of links attached to the node $i$.

My question is how this $|i \to j \rangle$, can be represented using binary coded bit string?

**Reference:** Discrete-time quantum walk on complex networks for community detection by Kanae Mukai

Comment: It's best if you don't use embedded images to express your question. One of the main reasons being that if the image hosting site removes the image, the question becomes useless.

Comment: The question should be why would you like to represent it by a bitstring? There are certainly numerous ways of doing that (label all the edges, convert the labels into binary), but this seems pointless without an interpretation

Comment: As you can see this is the generic time equation for quantum walk, where degree of each node is not same (Non-regular graph). So, i and j both represent nodes here. While doing quantum walk I can only be present at some node not edge. So, I wanted to know how this  |i↦j⟩ can be represented using qubits. What I am thinking is, if node i and node j has edge, then we take tensor product of node i and j. Is it right?

Comment: Binshumeshsachan could you type up the photo like @Rammus said? It really is for the best of the community (and people trying to answer the question) if it's all internal to QCSE